# Value Overwritten by Copy Constructor in the Priority Queue

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, reference, copy-constructor

The objective of the following Test code is to order the tasks according to their priority using priority queue.

Expected output of the program is    : **4 3 2 1**

But the program gives me the result  : **1 3 3 3**

**Problem 1:**
I can understand that **'prio'** value which is passed by reference through **param** have overwritten by copy constructor and copy assignment operator but I don't know how to avoid it.

**Problem 2:**
Why the compiler explicitly require the  **copy constructor and copy assignment operator** to be defined even though I'm not allocating any memory in the constructor ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm> 

template<typename T, typename Param>
class Task
{
 public:
   typedef void (T::*Func)(Param&);

    T* object;
    Func func;
    Param& param;
    int priority;

    Task(T& obj_, Func f_, Param& p_, int pp)
         :object(&obj_), func(f_), param(p_),priority(pp) { }
    virtual ~Task() {}
    virtual void operator()() const { (object->*func)(param); }
    // WHY I NEED COPY CONSTRUCTOR AND COPY ASSIGNMENT ???
    // Copy Constructor -- Not sure... I need to allocate new memory ??
    Task(const Task& obj)
     :object(obj.object), func(obj.func), param(obj.param),priority(obj.priority)
      {  
      }
    // Copy Assignment Operator
    Task& operator=(const Task obj){
        object= obj.object; func = obj.func; param = obj.param;
        priority = obj.priority;            
        return *this;
     }
};
```

// Predicate: Highest Priority Task should be at the top of the queue

```
struct TaskCompare
{
   template<typename T, typename Param>
   bool operator()(const Task< T,Param > &t1, const Task< T,Param > &t2) const 
  {
    return t1.priority < t2.priority;       
   }
};


template<typename T, typename Param>
class taskQ
{
public:
    std::priority_queue<Task< T,Param >, std::vector<Task< T,Param > >,
                                              TaskCompare> queue;

    void addTask(T& t, void (T::*f)(Param&), Param& p_, int pri) {
    queue.push(Task< T,Param >( t, f, p_, pri));
     }

     void executeTask() {   
         while(!queue.empty()) {
             queue.top()();
             queue.pop();
            }

     }
};

typedef struct Param_t {           
    int prio;   
}Param_t;

class Core {
public:
    Core() {}
    void print(Param_t& p) { std::cout<<p.prio;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  taskQ<Core,Param_t&> t;
  Core *c = new Core();
  Param_t param;
  param.prio= 3;    
  t.addTask(*c,&Core::print, param,param.prio);
  Param_t param1;
  param1.prio= 1;        
  t.addTask(*c,&Core::print, param1,param1.prio);
  Param_t param2;
  param2.prio= 2;    
  t.addTask(*c,&Core::print, param2,param2.prio);
  Param_t param3;
  param3.prio = 4;
  t.addTask(*c,&Core::print, param3,param3.prio);
  t.executeTask(); 

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: the code won't compile, add const to operator(), and change while condition in executeTask()

Comment: Why do you keep a reference to `param` instead of copy? It looks like the root cause of your pains (need for copy constructor and overwriting values)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. My kind opinion is passing reference is not a root cause. Bcos instead of using std::priority_queue if you use std::deque the code will work perfectly in FIFO order. Minor typo and coding standard are corrected. Many Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

your problem has been solved by taking arguments by value, not by reference:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm> 

template<typename T, typename Param>
class Task
{
 public:
   typedef void (T::*Func)(Param);

    T* object;
    Func func;
    Param param;
    int priority;

    Task(T& obj_, Func f_, Param p_, int pp)
         :object(&obj_), func(f_), param(p_),priority(pp) { }
    virtual ~Task() {}
    virtual void operator()() const { (object->*func)(param); }
    // WHY I NEED COPY CONSTRUCTOR AND COPY ASSIGNMENT ???
    // Copy Constructor -- Not sure... I need to allocate new memory ??
    Task(const Task& obj)
     :object(obj.object), func(obj.func), param(obj.param),priority(obj.priority)
      {  
      }
    // Copy Assignment Operator
    Task& operator=(const Task obj){
        object= obj.object; func = obj.func; param = obj.param;
        priority = obj.priority;            
        return *this;
     }
};

struct TaskCompare
{
   template<typename T, typename Param>
   bool operator()(const Task< T,Param > &t1, const Task< T,Param > &t2) const 
  {
    return t1.priority < t2.priority;       
   }
};


template<typename T, typename Param>
class taskQ
{
public:
    std::priority_queue<Task< T,Param >, std::vector<Task< T,Param > >,
                                              TaskCompare> queue;

    void addTask(T& t, void (T::*f)(Param), Param p_, int pri) {
    queue.push(Task< T,Param >( t, f, p_, pri));
     }

     void executeTask() {   
         while( !queue.empty()) {
             queue.top()();
             queue.pop();
            }

     }
};

typedef struct Param_t {           
    int prio;   
}Param_t;

class Core {
public:
    Core() {}
    void print(Param_t p) { std::cout<<p.prio;}
};
```

usage:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  taskQ<Core,Param_t> t;
  Core *c = new Core();
  Param_t param;
  param.prio= 3;    
  t.addTask(*c,&Core::print, param,param.prio);
  Param_t param1;
  param1.prio= 1;        
  t.addTask(*c,&Core::print, param1,param1.prio);
  Param_t param2;
  param2.prio= 2;    
  t.addTask(*c,&Core::print, param2,param2.prio);
  Param_t param3;
  param3.prio = 4;
  t.addTask(*c,&Core::print, param3,param3.prio);
  t.executeTask(); 

  return 0;
 }
```

prints:

4321
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 73ms)

Comment: For saving memory/time I'm passing "param" by reference (pls consider "param" has many data members) or this is one of my requirement. Passing by value method I already followed in passing the "param.prio" - this is not my problem. Thanks a lot and I greatly appreciate your time and effort.